# Hibernate HQL can't recognize table alias in sub select , Insert Into ... Select ... where column = (Select...)

Tags: hibernate, select, insert, subquery, hql

I have this HQL, you will notice that it contains two instances of the Same table TABLE_2 (tab2 and tab5) :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (column, column, column,
column, column, column, column, column)
SELECT column, column, column,
column, column, column, column, column
FROM TABLE_2 as tab2 INNER JOIN tab2.message as tab3 INNER JOIN tab3.service as tab4, TABLE_2 as tab5
WHERE tab2.dateChgt = (SELECT MAX(dateChgt) FROM TABLE_2 WHERE code = :pCd1 AND message.num = tab3.num GROUP BY message.num)
AND tab5.dateChgt = (SELECT MAX(dateChgt) FROM TABLE_2 WHERE code = :pCd2 AND message.num = tab3.num GROUP BY message.num)
AND tab2.code = :pcode1
AND tab5.code = :pcode2
AND tab2.message.num = tab5.message.num
AND tab2.dateChgt <= tab5.dateChgt
AND tab5.dateChgt >= :pDateDebRech
AND tab5.dateChgt <= :pDateFinRech
AND tab3.typeMessage = :pTypeMessage
GROUP BY tab3.num, tab4.column, tab4.column, tab3.column;
```

So the error is : invalid reference of an entry in the FROM clause for the "t_message" table.
Hint: Maybe you want to reference the alias of the table "tmessage1_".

The problem is that i have given the alias tab3 to t_message (tab2.message in HQL) but HQL won't recongnize the alias tab3 in the sub Select when i call tab3.num.

Amazingly, the problem desapears when i remove the Insert into statement and transfer the query to a simple Select query. Also i tried to run the query on PgAdmin (Database is PostgreSql), it works, so the problem comes from HQL i suppose.

Any Ideas ?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

That's most probably a Hibernate bug. You should create an issue here https://hibernate.atlassian.net/ along with a test case: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java